# Dividing Two Infinities

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

I am Curious if the following is mathematically correct:

Let $a$ be the infinite set of all nonnegative integers $0,1,2,3...$.

Let $b$ be the infinite set of all nonnegative EVEN integers $0,2,4,6...$.

If I take the sum of $a$ and divide it by the sum of $b$ do I get 2?

Is this correct? Can one divide infinities like this?

If yes, does this mean that SUM $a$ > SUM $b$ (despite that both are infinite)?

(if this is not possible can one do some kind of equivalent division using mapping of sets?)

Comment: When you say the sum of $a$, do you mean the number of elements in $a$ or the sum $0+1+2+3+\cdots$? Either way, the sum is divergent and hence not a number, so you can't "divide infinities like this".

Comment: i meant the latter. if you do a one to one mapping then it seems the first set will be twice as big, no?

Comment: Because you are talking about one to one mappings in your comment, it seems like you might be interested in cardinalities rather than in infinite series.  These are (almost) entirely different topics, so it would be good to know more precisely what you are wondering about.

Comment: (By the way, it seems like you are mixing up the roles of $a$ and $b$ in your question.)

Answer (score 5):

It is mathematically incorrect, but the idea is intuitively good in certain contexts. The right way to say things is that it all depends on how you take the limits. Since both series sum to infinity, you need to make your result "$2$" precise. For instance,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n} 2i }{\sum_{i=0}^n i}
$$
is probably what you had in mind when you thought of the result being "two". Of course, this limit is worth two, but we cannot say 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n} 2i }{\sum_{i=0}^n i} = \frac{\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n 2i}{\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^n i}
$$
because the two "things" on the numerator and denominator are not numbers, so their ratio is not *a priori* defined. To understand what I mean better, notice that if we tweak things a little bit :P , it is not hard to show that 
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n} 2i }{\sum_{i=0}^{n^2} i}= 0, \qquad \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sum_{i=0}^{n^2} 2i }{\sum_{i=0}^{n} i}= \infty.
$$
Hope that helps,

Comment: thank you. However, still not clear why it doesn't work. after all the first set has all the integers in the second set. plus a copy of them shifted by 1. seems that no matter how far you stretch out the set, it should be only twice as big. perhaps in set theory this would work somehow?

Comment: @Ray S. : That's because you add the integers in the first set at a rate "nicely similar" as the rate at which you add them in the second set. Say you added a lot of integers in the set $b$ to get the number $b_n$ at the $n^{\text{th}}$ step, but only a little bit of the integers in the set $a$ to get $a_n$ at the $n^{\text{th}}$ step, you expect $a_n/b_n$ to remain small, even though you end up using all the integers to compute the $a_n$'s and the $b_n$'s. Try examples.

Comment: is there a way to do this with sets? maybe some kind of mapping?

Comment: @RayS. There is a way, but I think you need to understand better the notions of limits and convergent/divergent series before asking such questions, because you will not understand the issues before you try to go in the details.

Comment: Can you show that the two limits I considered above evaluate to $0$ and $\infty$? That would be a first step.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, your series are divergent, so their sums are not defined.

However, if you have a *convergent* infinite series, say $b_1 + b_2 + b_3 \cdots$ converges to $S$, and $c$ is a constant, then $cb_1 + cb_2 + cb_3 + \cdots$ converges to $cS$.

Moreover, given a second series $a_1 + a_2 +a_3 \cdots$, if $0 \le a_n \le b_n$ for all $n$, then the second series $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \cdots$ converges to a value less than or equal to $S$.  This is known as the *comparison test* for infinite series.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot divide the sum of the elements of $a$ by the sum of the elements of $b$. The reason is that what we expect out of our "normal" rules of addition, subtraction, multiplication and division become very tricky when infinity becomes involved.

This is seen very commonly in a number of misleading but seemingly correct manipulations. Consider, for instance, the infinite sum $$S = 1 + 2+ 4 + 8 + 16 + \cdots$$

Now multiply $S$ by 2 to find $$2S = 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + \cdots = S - 1$$

This would imply that $S = -1$, which is an absurd conclusion indeed!

Math is rife with examples like this where infinities are tricky to manage and must be handled with exceptional care. For more examples like these, the excellent notes of Dr. Tao are quite informative:

http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/131ah.1.03w/week1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't know very much about number theory so I am well suited to answer you, also being an amateur.

You cannot sum up infinitely many natural numbers. You can take the sum of the first n numbers, S1(n) and divide one with the other, S2(n) and then divide to get S1(n)/S2(n) and the find a limit as n goes to eternity, which means it doesn't change very much as n goes bigger and bigger. In some cases you can do this, but the series to be summed have to consist of smaller and smaller terms, and only some of those will work. 1+1/2+1/4 +1/8 can be summed up but 1+1/2+1/3+1/4... cannot.

Comment: I worked too long with my answer and posted it after  several other answers - people are really active here. I think you can disregard my answer (if you understand the others').

Comment: You *can* sum infinitely many natural numbers, it's just that the series obtained in this fashion will either give you a finite integer (if you are adding many many zeros :P ) or $\infty$. It is not non-sense to say that summing infinitely many things gives you $\infty$ as a result. What's non-sense is considering ratios of two *a priori* infinite quantities without discussing how.

And um... "...and the find a limit as n goes to eternity" 

Funny! You meant "infinity". That's the term we use in mathematics.